# If I delete synced Google contacts on my iPhone, does that affect my google contact?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, google-sync

I needed some of my gmail contacts to email them and get some info, so I decided to sync my google accounts to my iPhone.
The problem is that I have some repeated contacts and I want to delete those from the iPhone, but I don’t know if that will just delete them on the phone or if it’ll affect my google contacts too.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question!

Comment: For my knowledge, if you delete it using the contact app from iPhone it will delete from google contacts. You have the option to link the duplicated ones (considering they are not too much, because you have to do it one by one). Is linking them a valid option for you? Linking is like merging both contacts details into one person showing on iPhone's Contact App; In other words: Your problem is having 2 repeated contacts showing on iPhone (which is annoying), or your problem is that you want to not have duplicates at all [between google contatct and iPhone contatcs]?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only seeing the duplicates on your iPhone, they're most likely in different *Groups*. You can check this by opening *Contacts* on your phone and tapping the *Groups* button (screenshot below). If you see a group called iPhone, those are stored exclusively on your phone and deleting them will not affect your Google contacts. You can uncheck the Google group to show (and ensure you only delete) contacts from your phone. Deleting contacts from the Google group will affect your Google contacts.

[image: Viewing iPhone contact groups.]